# Django Superuser no longer working after implementing social login

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-authentication, saleor

I have recently implemented Social Login to my Django site (which is working), but have encountered an issue where if I create a superuser using the terminal that superuser login does not work.

Middleware Section of Settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django_babel.middleware.LocaleMiddleware',
    'graphql_jwt.middleware.JSONWebTokenMiddleware',
    'saleor.core.middleware.discounts',
    'saleor.core.middleware.google_analytics',
    'saleor.core.middleware.country',
    'saleor.core.middleware.currency',
    'saleor.core.middleware.site',
    'saleor.core.middleware.taxes',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
    'impersonate.middleware.ImpersonateMiddleware']
```

Authentication part of Settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'saleor.account.backends.facebook.CustomFacebookOAuth2',
    'saleor.account.backends.google.CustomGoogleOAuth2',
    'graphql_jwt.backends.JSONWebTokenBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
```

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "if I create a superuser using the terminal that superuser login does not work."?
In what ways it fails?
How are you creating the superuser?

Comment: there was an error with the code and not an issue with the settings.py file. The saleor superuser function was changed to make this work.